# Typescript Duplicate identifier error

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular-meteor

I am getting the following error when I try to run my angular-meteor client (ionic serve):

```
[00:29:20]  typescript: node_modules/meteor-typings/1.3/main.d.ts, line: 657 
            Duplicate identifier 'Status'. 

     L657:    type Status = 'connected' | 'connecting' | 'failed' | 'waiting' | 'offline';

[00:29:20]  typescript: node_modules/meteor-typings/1.3/main.d.ts, line: 695 
            Duplicate identifier 'Status'. 

     L695:      type Status = 'connected' | 'connecting' | 'failed' | 'waiting' | 'offline';

[00:29:20]  transpile failed
```

The error in the source code file is: `TS2300:Duplicate identifier 'Status'`.

The project is built using this tutorial: https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup
Most files are identical to here: https://github.com/Urigo/Ionic2CLI-Meteor-WhatsApp

```
Ionic Framework: 2.1.0
Ionic Native: 2.4.1
Ionic App Scripts: 1.1.3
Angular Core: 2.2.1
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.2.1
Node: 6.3.1
OS Platform: macOS Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

You can see all the involved [files in this codebase](https://github.com/Eraldo/coapp/).

Any ideas what is going on? Where to look next? I admit I am a bit lost.
I reverted all my code changes since it last worked and removed the node_modules and reinstalled the project requirements. I still get the same error although as far as I see it nothing changed.

I am grateful for any guidance/ideas.

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` look like? Are you sure `node_modules` folder is excluded?

Comment: Hello @Saravana, I added the link to the files. As far as I can tell the node_modules should be excluded as I have an `"exclude"` section in my `tsconfig.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this in my tsconfig file:

```
"types": [
  "meteor-typings",
  "@types/underscore"
]
```

As soon as I removed 'meteor-typings', it worked!

```
"types": [
  "@types/underscore"
]
```

In my package.json file I have:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.3",
    "@types/meteor": "^1.3.32",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.7.36",
    "meteor-typings": "^1.3.1",
    "tmp": "0.0.31",
    "typescript": "2.0.9",
    "typescript-extends": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

Somehow I guess it was already part of the transpile process and the additional line in tsconfig made it appear doubly so. (This is my personal guess and I do not know why) :)

Comment: This results in 'Mongo is not defined' error for me, did you change other configuration?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I started having this problem when I updated Ionic from 2.0.0 to 2.2.0.

The fix worked for me and I had the exact tsconfig.json file as in the tutorial:

```
"types": [
  "meteor-typings",
  "@types/underscore",
  "@types/meteor-accounts-phone",
  "@types/meteor-collection-hooks"
]
```

Removing "meteor-typings" fixed the problem. I am not sure why.

So I expect the tutorial may need updating as when someone updates to the latest Ionic.  I will post an issue in their github repo.

Comment: Thanks Andy for confirming the fix I suggested works for you too. And thanks for creating an issue on github. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify further: Within the api/tsconfig.json you leave the "meteor-typings" in types[] as is. Inside the root folder you remove the additional "meteor-typings" inside types[] then it should run without errors. Dont forget to add the softlink to node_modules inside the api folder.

For windows users this is done with:

```
mklink /d \node_modules ..\node_modules
```

There should be no package.json inside the api folder as described inside the tutorial.

Thanks for the fix.